# Forms & HTML Laravel Collective. Почему не удаётся добавить класс к полю пароля?

Tags: laravel

Не работает добавление классов к полю password:

```
{!! Form::password('password', null, array('class' => 'awesome')) !!}
```

Зато прекрасно работает на поле text:

```
{!! Form::text('email', 'example@gmail.com', array('class' => 'input-block-level form-control m-b ' )) !!}
```

Подскажите/укажите где ошибка?

Comment: Важная строчка, которую зачем-то удалили при правке: _пакет Forms & HTML Laravel Collective_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Метод `Form::password(string $name, array $options = [])` не принимает дефолтное значение, поэтому правильно будет так:

```
{!! Form::password('password', array('class' => 'awesome')) !!}
```